# Verificar se existe registro na tabela

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, query, select

Estou tentando verificar se existe um registro na tabela do mysql usando php,

Eu tenho a tabela "slug", e nesta tabela tenho "id" e "slug_name", como faço o para verificar se existe já um nome nesta tabela, por exemplo: noticia_sobre_o_tempo.
como faço para ver se já existe esse nome, na tabela, depos do select.

```
public function verificar($name){
$string = (string) $name;
$data = $conexao->query('SELECT * FROM slug);
}
```

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, repare que está faltando o fechamento da aspa em sua query....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer :

```
public function verificar($name)
{    $string = (string) $name;
     $data = $conexao->query('SELECT * FROM slug');
     $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
     if($linha['slug_name'] != $string)
     {      echo "Não existe";
     }else
     {   echo "Já existe!";
     }
}
```

Precisa melhorar a `query`, mas é um caminho.

Comment: Oque é essa variável $senha ?

Answer (score 1):

Simples amigo, você ira usar a clausulá `Where` do mysql.

Vou dar um exemplo usando um código para buscar um usuário (com pdo).

```
$hostDB = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=opentagv3";
$usuarioServidor = "root";
$senhaServidor = "123456";

try {
  $conexao = new PDO($hostDB, $usuarioServidor, $senhaServidor);
  $conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $erroNaConexao) {
  echo $erroNaConexao->getMessage();
  echo "<br>"."Erro ao Conectar com o Banco de Dados";
}

function buscaUsuarioPorEmail($email){
        $select = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'");
        $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select->execute();
        $usuario = $select->fetch();
        return $usuario;
    }
```

Esse `select` diz assim: "Me devolva todos os usuários que tem esse e-mail".. e a minha função recebe a variável e-mail como parâmetro. Se no final da função retornar `null`, o usuário com aquele e-mail não existe.

No seu caso seria..

```
public function verificar($name){
$select = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM slug where slug_name='$name'");
        $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select->execute();
        $slug= $select->fetch();
        return $slug;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas para ver se exite não teria que fazer uma contagem de linhas ?

Comment: Existem outras formas de verificar se contem um registro, neste caso estou usando uma variável para guardar o resultado, e se for null é porque não existe, mas poderia usar o método row e fazer um if para verificar se as linhas afetadas foram 0

Comment: Entendi, no meu caso e o seguinte, Preciso que retorne false ou true, para eu receber via ajax, para quando eu digitar o nome, me mostre em tempo real se existe ou não.

Comment: Só fazer um if na variável que recebe o fetch(), e retornar true ou false